# Different aggregation fields in same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I am trying to aggregate some fields in different way - using partition - in the same query but found a problem with AVG():

Take this definition:

```
CREATE TABLE Result
    (CheckListId int, CheckId int, AuditId int, CheckListResult FLOAT, CheckResult FLOAT)
INSERT INTO Result VALUES (1,1,1,1,1) 
INSERT INTO Result VALUES (1,2,1,1,3) 
INSERT INTO Result VALUES (1,2,2,3,1) 
INSERT INTO Result VALUES (2,1,1,3,1)

+-------------+---------+---------+-----------------+-------------+
| CheckListId | CheckId | AuditId | CheckListResult | CheckResult |
+-------------+---------+---------+-----------------+-------------+
|           1 |       1 |       1 |               1 |           1 |
|           1 |       2 |       1 |               1 |           3 |
|           1 |       2 |       2 |               3 |           1 |
|           2 |       1 |       1 |               3 |           1 |
+-------------+---------+---------+-----------------+-------------+
```

thanks to [Format Text as Table](https://senseful.github.io/web-tools/text-table/) for formatting

this is my select

```
 SELECT 
CheckListId
, CheckId
, (dense_rank() over (PARTITION BY CheckListId order by [AuditId]) 
+ dense_rank() over (PARTITION BY CheckListId order by [AuditId] desc) 
- 1) AS N_AuditForCheckList
, AVG(CheckListResult)  OVER(PARTITION BY CheckListId) AS AvgCheckListResult
, COUNT(AuditId) OVER (PARTITION BY CheckListId, CheckId) AS N_AuditForCheck
, AVG(CheckResult)  OVER(PARTITION BY CheckListId, CheckId) AS AvgCheckResult
FROM Result
```

i get this result

```
+-------------+---------+---------------------+--------------------+-----------------+----------------+
| CheckListId | CheckId | N_AuditForCheckList | AvgCheckListResult | N_AuditForCheck | AvgCheckResult |
+-------------+---------+---------------------+--------------------+-----------------+----------------+
|           1 |       1 |                   2 | 1,67               |               1 |              1 |
|           1 |       2 |                   2 | 1,67               |               2 |              2 |
|           1 |       2 |                   2 | 1,67               |               2 |              2 |
|           2 |       1 |                   1 | 3                  |               1 |              1 |
+-------------+---------+---------------------+--------------------+-----------------+----------------+
```

while in `AvgCheckListResult` i want `2` because on this checklist i have two results: 1 on first audit and 3 on second audit, while sql calculate avg of the 3 rows

Is there a way to do it without sub-query or joining many query?

p.s.

link to test it:
http://rextester.com/ZFEXOD67600

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe i found a solution with nested query:

```
SELECT * 
    ,(SELECT AVG(T.CheckListResult)
    FROM 
     (SELECT DISTINCT AuditId, CheckListId, CheckListResult FROM Result) as T
    WHERE T.CheckListId = Base.CheckListId  
    ) AS AvgCheckListResult
    ,(SELECT COUNT(T.CheckListResult)
    FROM 
     (SELECT DISTINCT AuditId, CheckListId, CheckListResult FROM Result) as T
    WHERE T.CheckListId = Base.CheckListId  
    ) AS N_AuditForCheckList
    ,(SELECT AVG(T.CheckResult)
    FROM 
     (SELECT DISTINCT AuditId, CheckId, CheckResult FROM Result) as T
    WHERE T.CheckId = Base.CheckId  
    ) AS AvgCheckResult

FROM Result AS Base
```

result is correct but not sure about performance

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find (at moment) how to do without a sub query (but I think you already explored my following solution): 
P.S. A +1 for the way you wrote your question (scripts, sample data, etc.)

```
SELECT * 
,  SUM(CheckListResult / C3  ) OVER (PARTITION BY CheckListId)  / N_AuditForCheckList AS AvgChk3

FROM (
    SELECT 
    CheckListId
    , CheckId
    , AuditId
    , CheckListResult
    , (dense_rank() over (PARTITION BY CheckListId order by [AuditId]) 
    + dense_rank() over (PARTITION BY CheckListId order by [AuditId] desc) 
    - 1) AS N_AuditForCheckList
    , AVG(CheckListResult)  OVER(PARTITION BY CheckListId) AS AvgCheckListResult

    , AVG(CheckListResult)  OVER(PARTITION BY CheckListId,AuditId) AS AvgCheckListResult2
    , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CheckListId, AuditId) AS C3

    , COUNT(AuditId) OVER (PARTITION BY CheckListId, CheckId) AS N_AuditForCheck
    , AVG(CheckResult) OVER(PARTITION BY CheckListId, CheckId) AS AvgCheckResult

    FROM Result) A
```

Output:

```
+-------------+---------+---------+-----------------+---------------------+--------------------+---------------------+----+-----------------+----------------+---------+
| CheckListId | CheckId | AuditId | CheckListResult | N_AuditForCheckList | AvgCheckListResult | AvgCheckListResult2 | C3 | N_AuditForCheck | AvgCheckResult | AvgChk3 |
+-------------+---------+---------+-----------------+---------------------+--------------------+---------------------+----+-----------------+----------------+---------+
|           1 |       1 |       1 |               1 |                   2 |   1,66666666666667 |                   1 |  2 |               1 |              1 |       2 |
|           1 |       2 |       1 |               1 |                   2 |   1,66666666666667 |                   1 |  2 |               2 |              2 |       2 |
|           1 |       2 |       2 |               3 |                   2 |   1,66666666666667 |                   3 |  1 |               2 |              2 |       2 |
|           2 |       1 |       1 |               3 |                   1 |                  3 |                   3 |  1 |               1 |              1 |       3 |
+-------------+---------+---------+-----------------+---------------------+--------------------+---------------------+----+-----------------+----------------+---------+
```